# Grammar and Meaning in Context SUMMIS

Tags: plural

I have a choral text set to music by Anton Bruckner. (I do not know Bruckner's source.) The text *VIRGA JESSE* reads as follows:

> VIRGA JESSE FLORUIT
>   VIRGO DEUM ET HOMINEM GENUIT
>   PACEM DEUS REDDIDIT
>   IN SE RECONCILIANS IMA SUMMIS

I have a question regarding the grammar of *SUMMIS*. If I see it correctly, this is dative or ablative plural of *SUMMUM* or *SUMMUS* (syntactically, it could also be coming from *SUMMA*, but this does not make sense semantically).

Why is this plural?

I read the last verse as *In himself reconciling the lowest with the highest* (the english language does not distinguish between plural and singular of *the highest*, so my problem is getting lost in translation into English). I do not understand why *the highest* is plural here? I would assume that it refers to God himself, who reconciles the temporal with the eternal when he becomes flesh, so I don't understand the use of plural.

Is there a sophisticated theological reason for the ocurrence of plural here? Or is *SUMMIS* just "wrong" grammar? Or (most probably) do I get something wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your difficulty. In your translation you have RECONSILIANS reconciling (nominative, like DEUS); IN SE within himself (in+Ablative position); IMA the lowest (the Object: Accusative neuter plural): SUMMIS to the highest / with the highest (Dative / Ablative neuter plural).

Comment: Lewis and Short say it must be Dative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both *īma* and *summīs* are neuter plural in this case: "the lowest things" and "the highest things".

The adjectives are being used in a sort of general sense here, rather than referring to any specific objects—God is reconciling everything that is lowly with everything that is exalted, without any particular lowly and exalted things in mind.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I agree with the grammatical analysis of ima possibly being plural as well - I didn't see that before. And I am fine with that explanation, hence I accepted your answer. I am just curious: How did you identify that *IMA SUMMIS* is short for *IMA RES SUMMIS REBUS*  here? Is omitting forms of *RES* a common thing (like omitting forms of *ESSE*)? Do you know other examples of this phenomenon?

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach I know it as "substantive use" of the adjective, and it's quite common: compare English _the good [people], the bad [people], and the ugly [people]_, or proverbs like _the good [people] die young_. In this particular case you can't actually supply _res_ because that would be feminine—the "things" is implicit in the neuter-plural-ness of the expression.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: „die Höchsten mit den Niedrigsten“

Comment: @fdb Ja, ich versteh schon. Mir war nur nicht klar, worauf sich das beziehen soll, also wer oder was mit "den Höchsten" gemeint sein soll.